# How to scroll a FlowDocument which has another FlowDocument in an Expander on it

Tags: wpf, xaml, flowdocument, expander

I am writing an app which displays reference information to the user in the form of a flow document, each reference includes a section of sub-references on the for inside an expander control. Some simplified code which demonstrates the structure:

```
<FlowDocumentScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph FontWeight="Bold">some title</Paragraph>
        <Paragraph FontWeight="Bold">sub title</Paragraph>
        <Paragraph>lots of body text</Paragraph>
        <Paragraph>lots of body text</Paragraph>
        <Paragraph>lots of body text</Paragraph>
        <Paragraph>lots of body text</Paragraph>
        <Paragraph>lots of body text</Paragraph>
        <Paragraph>lots of body text</Paragraph>
        <Paragraph>lots of body text</Paragraph>
        <Paragraph>
            <Expander Header="references" Background="{x:Null}">
                <FlowDocumentScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Background="{x:Null}">
                    <FlowDocument Background="{x:Null}">
                        <Section Padding="10,10,10,10" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="#FFB4B4B4" Background="#FFF0F0F0">
                            <Paragraph>lots of text</Paragraph>
                            <Paragraph>lots of text</Paragraph>
                            <Paragraph>lots of text</Paragraph>
                            <Paragraph>lots of text</Paragraph>
                            <Paragraph>lots of text</Paragraph>
                            <Paragraph>lots of text</Paragraph>
                            <Paragraph>lots of text</Paragraph>
                        </Section>
                    </FlowDocument>
                </FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
            </Expander>
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
```

My issue is that when the expander is expanded in order to show the cross referenced references then when the mouse is over the sub-reference the main flow document no longer scrolls. When the mouse is over the main reference the scrolling works fine.

I have tried numerous combinations of scroll bar settings but cannot figure it out.

**EDIT:**
Ok, so I managed to do it by changing the FlowDocumentScrollViewer contained in the Expander control to instead be a FlowDocumentReader. This fixed the scroll issue but meant I had to template the FlowDocumentReader in order to hide the toolbar which is shows by default.

But, annoyingly, the FlowDocumentReader is a heavier control resource wise and also always shows a vertical scrollbar when in scroll mode. I need to turn off the scroll bar as when contained in the structure I have, the control is at full length with the parent FlowDocumentScrollView handling the scrolling.

Ideally I would still want to use the FlowDocumentScrollView but need to resolve the scroll issue.